# Combine two different array of object based on matching field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different arrays of objects and need to combine both and the expecting the end result as

```
[
{
    "scenario": [
        {
            "errorname": "Error 01",
            "status": 5,
            "desc_1" : "test",
            "desc_2" : "testing"
        },
        {
            "errorname": "Error 03",
            "status": 0,
            "desc_1" : "test",
            "desc_2" : "testing"
        },
        {
            "errorname": "Error 09",
            "status": 0,
            "desc_1" : "test",
            "desc_2" : "testing"
        }
    ], 
    "completed": 0,
    "accessid": "1627047023995",
    "oid": 111111
}
```

]

scenario.errorname in "a" should match with b errorname.name value. i tried to map and combine both the array values, but not getting the expecting value. The result should match the errorname and combine both the array to create a new one

```js
let a = [{
  "scenario": [{
      "errorname": "Error 01",
      "status": 5
    },
    {
      "errorname": "Error 03",
      "status": 0
    },
    {
      "errorname": "Error 09",
      "status": 0
    }
  ],
  "completed": 0,
  "accessid": "1627047023995",
  "oid": 111111
}];

let b = [{
    "errorname": [{
        "name": "Error 01",
        "desc_1": "Test",
        "desc_2": "Testing"
      },
      {
        "name": "Error 03",
        "desc_1": "Test",
        "desc_2": "Testing"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "errorname": [{
        "name": "Error 02",
        "desc_1": "Test",
        "desc_2": "Testing"
      },
      {
        "name": "Error 09",
        "desc_1": "Test",
        "desc_2": "Testing"
      },
    ]
  }
]

const c = a.map(t1 => ({ ...t1,
  ...b.find(t2 => t2.errorname.name === t1.scenario.errorname)
}))
console.log(c)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you want to have as a result? EDIT: My bad, already provided.

Comment: @leodriesch The expected result was the first thing he mentioned. The arrays in the snippet are the inputs.

Comment: both `.errorname` and `.scenario` reference arrays not objects, so `.errorname.name` doesn't work. You'll need a nested find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will try and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of first making a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) from array `b` keyed by `name` and then using this to access the relevant `error` object in the `map()` call on array `a`.

```js
const a = [{ "scenario": [{ "errorname": "Error 01", "status": 5 }, { "errorname": "Error 03", "status": 0 }, { "errorname": "Error 09", "status": 0 }], "completed": 0, "accessid": "1627047023995", "oid": 111111 }];
const b = [{ "errorname": [{ "name": "Error 01", "desc_1": "Test: 01", "desc_2": "Testing" }, { "name": "Error 03", "desc_1": "Test: 03", "desc_2": "Testing" },], }, { "errorname": [{ "name": "Error 02", "desc_1": "Test: 02", "desc_2": "Testing" }, { "name": "Error 09", "desc_1": "Test: 09", "desc_2": "Testing" },] }];

// Map { 'Error 01' => { desc_1: 'Test', desc_2: 'Testing' }, 'Error 03' => {...}, ...}
const errorMap = new Map(b
  .flatMap(o => o.errorname)
  .map(({ name, ...e }) => [name, e]));

const result = a.map(t1 => (
  {
    ...t1,
    scenario: t1.scenario.map(s => ({ ...s, ...errorMap.get(s.errorname) }))
  }));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Pilchard. It works fine for a and b values provided. but when i try to load the values from api call. i am getting values merge result value with _parentArray, index and so on

Comment: Without seeing your actual API data I can't help I'm afraid. Can you post a small sample of the raw API data?

Comment: Yes the api return data for b = [
  {
    errorname: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  },
  {
    errorname: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  } 
]

Comment: and for "a" it is the same as given in the example, even for b, the value is the sample one as in the example. I copied the response and provided values for a and b manually and it works but when I get values directly from the call. it gives such a result

Comment: Is it inside a result object maybe? Sounds like you're not accessing the right level of the response.

Comment: the object has values like { "name": "Error 01", "status": 5 }

Comment: Did you parse the incoming JSON properly? I'd love to help but you'll need to show a sample of the full API response structure. Maybe make a code sandbox or stackblitz.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words. Yes, I parsed the response data. The application is running in local machine, I will add in sandbox and update